# CSRF defense using backbone and node.js

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, csrf

I'm creating a website using backbone and node.js and don't think that by default there is any protection against CSRF. Is there a standard way to project against CSRF when using backbone with node.js?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You could simply ensure requests have the `X-Requested-By` header with the value `XMLHTTPRequest`. AJAX requests have cross-domain restrictions so if that header is present it was not e.g. a hidden form on a malicious website.

Comment: doesn't that depend on the browser preventing cross domain ajax requests?

Comment: You can't depend on the fact that **common** browsers stop that behavior. It's entirely *opt-in* on the client side and **CAN'T** be trusted. What if I implemented a malicious client with [zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org) ?

Comment: @DavidEllis: You did NOT understand what CSRF is. If you implement a malicious client it will not have the IP or cookies of an authenticated user. So requests from that client are completely harmless. CSRF is not to prevent scripts from accessing your website but to prevent hidden forms etc. on malicious websites to access your website with the credentials of a legit user of your site.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, CSRF prevention isn't just for preventing account access -- a malicious client that's intentionally trying to crash your server by POSTing maliciously-crafted form won't be prevented by just checking the ``X-Requested-By`` header. It's much better to work from the perspective that you **can't trust the client** and all input should be scrutinized equally. My problem was with how flippant your response was with respect to site security.

Comment: Such a client would simply send the proper CSRF token.

Comment: but couldn't I simply spoof those headers if were to spam a site which depends simply with those headers?

Comment: This question is about CSRF which relies on the client performing the request - so his authentication is used. But if *you* spoof those headers that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anything specific for node.js + backbone, but you can use http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/middleware-csrf.html (assuming you're using express or something connect-compatible). You'll need to output the token somewhere in your html, like as a meta tag. Then you can modify the backbone sync method to pull that token and pass it to express via header, query, or form.

Answer (score 1):

If the `Allow-Origin` header is set to something permissive (e.g., `Allow-Origin:*`) `X-Requested-By` will not prevent request forgeries. Any javascript running on another host will be able to craft requests that still enable request forgeries.