# Symfony 2 CSFR protection and Backbone Application

Tags: symfony, backbone.js, csrf-protection

I have a CRUD controller on Symfony 2. I want to make a backbone application wrapper for this controller. But in the logic of the application there is a question: **"How to implement CSRF protection for the backbone forms application?"**

I see a few ways:

1. Request token before generating forms.
2. Generate underscore templates incorporating the tokens.
3. Disable protection in Symfony and invent your bike.

I will be glad for your help in choosing the right solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, I hurried to the question.
Here is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386373/csrf-defense-using-backbone-and-node-js)
From myself I want to add the solution to Symfony server side:

```
$options=array();
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest() )         
    $options['csrf_protection']= false;
$form = $this->createForm(new FormType(), $entity,$options);
```

Comment: this is by no means the "solution", unless you are happy with an insecure application

Comment: Do you have some ideas for this problem?