# How to protect against CSRF when using Backbone.js to post data?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, web, csrf

Backbone.js handles posting data to server under the hood, so there is no easy way to insert a CSRF token in the payload. How can I protect my site against CSRF in this situation?

In this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10386412/954376, the suggestion is to verify the x-Requested-By header to be XMLHTTPRequest. Is this enough to block all CSRF attempts?

In Django docs, the suggestion is to add CSRF token in another custom header in every AJAX request: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax. Is this necessary?

I understand if the attack uses hidden form, I am safe by just assuring the request is from XMLHTTPRequest. But is there any CSRF attack tricks that can forge the header?

Comment: "I am safe by just assuring the request is from XMLHTTPRequest" — You can't ensure that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [prefilter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/) to add the token to all requests:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(opts) {
    if (opts.data) {
        opts.data += "&";
    }
    opts.data += "csrfToken=" + token;
});
```

You may need to add additional logic if you don't always send the token.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So just verifying the X-Requested-with header is no good? What kind of attack can forge this header?

Comment: @NeoWang Those that use bugs in plugins like Flash. You cannot forge the header in a normal CSRF situation, so it's fine without bugs. You might consider that always just sending and checking token is much simpler than sometimes checking token and sometimes checking header.

Answer (score 15):

Setting a global CSRF-token for all jQuery.ajax calls:

```
$(function(){ 
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {'X-CSRFToken': CSRF_TOKEN}
  });
})
```

Setting the token just for Backbone by overriding Backbone.sync:

```
var oldSync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options){
  options.beforeSend = function(xhr){
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', CSRF_TOKEN);
  };
  return oldSync(method, model, options);
};
```

EDIT: Fixed a typo Kadam points at in comments

Comment: The correct spelling of the header key is `X-CSRFToken`. There is an extra dash in your first suggestion that breaks it.

Comment: @kadam the correct spelling of the header key depends on the server. For example, Express 3 uses `X-CSRF-Token`. http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#csrf

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated version, based in [Django 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) (using the jQuery cookie plugin)

```
oldSync = Backbone.sync
Backbone.sync = (method, model, options) ->

    csrfSafeMethod = (method) ->
        # these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        /^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test method

    options.beforeSend = (xhr, settings) ->
        if !csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) and !@crossDomain
            xhr.setRequestHeader 'X-CSRFToken', $.cookie('csrftoken')
        return
    oldSync method, model, options
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit old question, but I'll leave a link to the github repo of AMD module just for this:

https://github.com/kuc2477/backbone.csrf.git (*disclaimer: I'm the author of the module*)